# Как в bootstrap 4 сделать так чтобы блоки растягивались по высоте

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, flexbox

Нужно сделать так что бы в колонке bootstrap был вложенный блок-карточка товара.У блока должны быть границы со всех сторон,внутри col, и он должен тянулся по высоте, в зависимости от контента

Единственное что смог придумать это задать класс со свойством display:flex; col - элементу bootstrap.Но не хочу завязываться на bootstrap классах
Подскажите что можно сделать?

```css
.d {
  flex: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.g {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="g">
      fsd
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="g">
      df<br>d
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="g">
      fd
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/scordavis/jz9sgcz5/

```
<div class="row align-items-stretch b-height">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="g">
      fsd
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Если не хотите привязываться к BootsTrap-классам - для чего тогда использовать фреймворк?